# R: How to obtain diagnostic plots for a lavaan mediation model?

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I wasn't sure whether this was more appropriate to ask here or CrossValidated as I'm specifically asking about using R / `lavaan`...

I'm not sure if I've completely misunderstood how violations of assumptions are checked. I understand that we can obtain diagnostic plots for linear models with:

```
model <- lm(data$outcome ~ data$predictor)

plot(model, which = c(1:6))
```

But I'm having trouble figuring out how I should do this for a mediation model fitted like so:

```
model <- 'outcome ~ c*predictor + b*mediator
              mediator ~ a*predictor
              indirect_effect := a*b
              total_effect := c + (a*b)
              '

model.fit <- lavaan::sem(
  model = model,
  data = data,
  missing = "FIML",
  estimator = "ML")
```

Then if I try obtaining plots in the same way (`plot(model.fit, which = c(1:6))`), I get `Error in as.double(y) :  cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'`.

Also, to check for violations of assumptions for Pearson's correlation, would we do so by looking at the structure of each variable individually, or by making a linear model (`lm(data$outcome ~ data$predictor)`), or using the correlation itself (`cor.test(data$var1, data$var2)`) in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
lavaanPlot::lavaanPlot(model = model.fit, coefs=T)
```